# Setting up IRQ mapping

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, irq

I'm following several tutorials and references trying to get my kernel set up. I've come across some unfamiliar code in a tutorial that isn't explaining it at all. It's code that I'm told maps the `16 IRQs (0-15)` to ISR locations `32-47`:

```
void irq_remap(void)
{
    outportb(0x20, 0x11);
    outportb(0xA0, 0x11);
    outportb(0x21, 0x20);
    outportb(0xA1, 0x28);
    outportb(0x21, 0x04);
    outportb(0xA1, 0x02);
    outportb(0x21, 0x01);
    outportb(0xA1, 0x01);
    outportb(0x21, 0x0);
    outportb(0xA1, 0x0);
}
```

The code for `outportb()` is as follows, but I already have a clear grasp of what its doing:

```
void outPortB(unsigned short port, unsigned char data)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %1, %0" : : "dN" (port), "a" (data));
}
```

I should mention that this is on x86 architecture in protected mode. This source code works fine and I understand what it does, but I don't understand how it does it. Can someone explain to me what's going on here, so that in case I need to expand on this I will know what I'm doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`outb` and similar, write to hardware IO ports. Basically, there are 2 primary options for communicating with a device. You can have the device mapped to memory or IO ports.

As for how this code works, i'll comment it for you:

ICW stands for "Initialization Commands Words"

```
outportb(0x20, 0x11); /* write ICW1 to PICM, we are gonna write commands to PICM */
outportb(0xA0, 0x11); /* write ICW1 to PICS, we are gonna write commands to PICS */

outportb(0x21, 0x20); /* remap PICM to 0x20 (32 decimal) */
outportb(0xA1, 0x28); /* remap PICS to 0x28 (40 decimal) */

outportb(0x21, 0x04); /* IRQ2 -> connection to slave */ 
outportb(0xA1, 0x02);

outportb(0x21, 0x01); /* write ICW4 to PICM, we are gonna write commands to PICM */
outportb(0xA1, 0x01); /* write ICW4 to PICS, we are gonna write commands to PICS */

outportb(0x21, 0x0); /* enable all IRQs on PICM */
outportb(0xA1, 0x0); /* enable all IRQs on PICS */
```

hope this helps

Welcome to the world of OS dev :) I also recommend that you visit: http://forum.osdev.org/, it is an invaluable resource for a new hobby OS developer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that in protected mode the interrupts used by the 1st Programmable Interrupt Controller are protected mode exceptions, which means that they have to be remapped.

> 

The happy answer is that only the first `PIC` needs to be remapped ( the remapping of the second is only for convenience since it begins at `int 70h`).
Here's a quote from the original AT BIOS.

```
INTA00    equ  020h        ; 8259 port
INTA01    equ  021h        ; 8259 port
INTB00    equ  0A0h        ; 2nd 8259
INTB01    equ  0A1h
INT_TYPE  equ  070h        ; start of 8259 interrupt table location

;---------------------------------------------------------
;    re-initialize the 8259 interrupt #1 controller chip :
;---------------------------------------------------------
  mov  al, 11h             ; icw1 - edge, master, icw4
  out  INTA00,al
  jmp  $+2                 ; wait state for i/o
  mov  al, 8               ; setup icw2 - int type 8 (8-f)
  out  INTA01, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, 4               ; setup icw3 - master lv 2
  out  INTA01, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, 1               ; setup icw4 - master, 8086 mode
  out  INTA01, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, 0FFh            ; mask all ints. off
  out  INTA01, al          ; (video routine enables interrupts)
;---------------------------------------------------------
;    re-initialize the 8259 interrupt #2 controller chip  :
;---------------------------------------------------------
  mov  al, 11h             ; icw1 - edge, slave icw4
  out  INTB00, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, INT_TYPE        ; setup icw2 - int type 70 (70-7f)
  out  INTB01, al
  mov  al, 2               ; setup icw3 - slave lv 2
  jmp  $+2
  out  INTB01, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, 1               ; setup icw4 - 8086 mode, slave
  out  INTB01, al
  jmp  $+2
  mov  al, 0FFh            ; mask all ints. off
  out  INTB01, al
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Technical Reference AT BIOS (c) 1984 IBM

Note:

The `jmp  $+2 ; wait state for i/o` is not required on a current PC.

The `icw1` clears the interrupt mask register, which enables the interrupts on that PIC.

The 8259A chip is long since gone but the programming interface is still used.
[8259A Programmable Interrupt Controller](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/hardware/8259A.pdf)